# What do I need to import to make `SparkConf` resolvable?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am setting up a Java Spark application and am following the [Datastax documentation on getting started with the Java API](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html). I've added

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

and (a previously installed `dse.jar` to my local Maven repository)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse</artifactId>
    <version>version number</version>
</dependency>
```

. Next step in the guide is to do

```
SparkConf conf = DseSparkConfHelper.enrichSparkConf(new SparkConf())
                .setAppName( "My application");
DseSparkContext sc = new DseSparkContext(conf);
```

. However, **the class `SparkConf` can't be resolved. Should it? Am I missing some additional Maven dependency? Which?**

Answer (score 0):

The class is `org.apache.spark.SparkConf` which is in the spark-core_*scala version* artifact.

So your pom.xml might look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
        <artifactId>dse</artifactId>
        <version>*version number*</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The spark-core JAR is also located in:
*dse_install*/resources/spark/lib/spark_core_2.10-*version*.jar (tarball)
or:
/usr/share/dse/spark/lib/spark_core_2.10-*version*.jar (package installs)

Comment: Thanks Ian - looks like that version of `spark-core_2.10` would yield an `InvalidClassException` just like all the other versions I've tried in http://stackoverflow.com/q/33782857/260805. Are you positive that it really should work?

Comment: PS. I added the `serialVersionUID` of the class I'm having issues with to this document: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/6dff9729079d04165e6f

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782857/can-i-use-regular-spark-core-application-library-to-talk-to-dse-spark